# Orders being placed for wrong store

Tags: php, session, magento, cookies, checkout

I am using Magento 1.3.2 in a multi-store setup. www.example.com is the main store, and abc.example.com, foo.example.com and bar.example.com are affiliate stores with separate subdomains, separate inventory, separate carts, separate designs.

My problem is that *some* orders being placed through the affiliates are showing up as coming from the main store. It doesn't happen frequently, maybe once in every 1000 orders. I notice these when I go to fulfill the order and I see that the SKU is not one of mine but rather it is one of the affiliate's, despite the fact that the website, store and store view on the order screen all show the main store. I know that the customers are adding the product to their cart from the affiliate site (we don't even list affiliate products on the main site) and they go through the checkout process on the affiliate site. Does anybody have any ideas what could be causing this?

EDIT: I wish I could recreate this so I could post some code that I think might be buggy or something else helpful, but I've tried every permutation I can think of (logging in on the affiliate site vs the main site, having two carts open, adding/removing products in various sequences) but I still can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: you can try to create fictive user and try every setting in order wizard to find out what setting/actions are causing this.

Comment: @MarekSebera Thanks for the reply. I've created multiple users to try and recreate this situation, with no luck. If I could recreate it consistently then I would definitely go through the settings trying to find something that fixed the problem. What is "order wizard"?

Comment: What about Share Customer Accounts option? (System->Configuration, in left menu CUSTOMERS->Customer Configuration->Account Sharing Options)?  Maybe your customer accounts are shared between all websites? Some customer signed up on main website uses his account on affiliate one?

Comment: @Zyava Yes, customer accounts are global. Carts however are not shared (I don't even know if there's an option for this in my version). So there's no way an affiliate product should even *appear* in a customer's cart when on the main website.

Comment: Wait, let's clear one thing. Is the whole order placed to the wrong store? Or in the same order you see products from different stores?

Comment: I'll double-check but I don't think I have ever seen an order with parts from two different stores. In all the instances I can think of it was a single affiliate part being ordered and placed to the wrong store.

Comment: Do you share baskets between sites? Could they be adding an item on one site and fulfil the order on another?

Comment: They could also add product to wishlist on one site and order product from wishlist on another site.

Comment: @StuR - Baskets are not shared. I was never able to recreate the situation you describe where an item is added on one site and the order was placed on the other.

Comment: @Zyava - We've disabled wishlists so I don't think that's it either.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow some steps :

- Make sure affiliates use different databases. Provide them with different database username/password sets. This ensures they are not messing with your database.
- Make sure you have CSRF tokens, Or some URL Redirection/DNS config would make orders of affiliates to end up on the main shop.
- If you feel like it, Browse web server logs to see what happened (might be time-consuming)
- Provide people you ask for help with your system configuration, e.g Web Server, Server-side Scripting Language, Database Server, Operating System, etc.
- If it is 1 in a 1000 problem, Then there are two general case of triggers for that:

  - Some particular costumers with particular system setup / clicking habits result in that.
  - You have concurrency problems in your code (Database Transactions?)

Hope it helped

Comment: I appreciate the response. I think I'm going to have to split off the affiliates into a separate install of Magento and just share the customer table between them. In regards to my system configuration, I don't know how this would help but the problem has been seen while running both Apache 2.0 and LiteSpeed web servers, using PHP 5.2.17, MySQL 5.0, CentOS 5.5.